# Do commutative rings without unity have the IBN property?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative rng, i.e. a commutative ring without an identity element.

> Does $R$ still have the Invariant Basis Number (IBN) property?

Recall that a ring is said to have the IBN property if $R^m \cong R^n \Rightarrow m=n$.

All commutative rings have the IBN property, but the standard proof I know makes an essential use of the existence of a maximal ideal by Zorn's Lemma and passing to the residue field, which depends on the presence of a unit.

Comment: Simply adjoint a unit to $R$ to obtain $R_1$ (e.g., $R_1 = R[x]/(r x - r : r \in R)$).  Then an isomorphism $R^m \cong R^n$ automatically extends to an isomorphism $R_1^m \cong R_1^n$, and you can use the IBN property for $R_1$.

Comment: The answer is "not necessarily". For a counterexample, let $R = \oplus^{\omega} \mathbb Z$ with zero multiplication.

Comment: It should be pointed out that $R^n$ doesn't have a basis either when $R$ is non-unital.

Comment: If $R$ is a rng, then $R^n$ doesn't have a basis!  (The usual basis would be the columns of an identity matrix, but we cannot make sense of the entry $1$!) What you've written still makes mathematical sense, of course, but it's still a little funny to call it the "invariant basis number" in this context.

Comment: @LSpice Your notation is ambiguous. An isomorphism $R^m\simeq R^n$ lifts to an isomorphism $(R^m)_1\simeq(R^n)_1$, but not necessarily to an isomorphism $(R_1)^m\simeq(R_1)^n$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, thanks.  I was wondering how to square my sloppy sketch with [@‍KeithKearnes](https://mathoverflow.net/a/313091)'s counterexample.

Comment: @KeithKearnes: thank you for this example! Clearly, I didn't think large enough. Since zero multiplication is somewhat artificial, I must ask how representative is your counter-example in terms of badness? In other words, do you happen to have an example with sufficiently non-trivial multiplication, for which the version of the IBN property, however improper, defined in my question still fails? Or is it mostly a size issue?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: thank you for pointing this out! I admit that at the moment of writing the question I did not pay attention that both notions of IBN property actually diverge from each other, but instead wanted to keep the formulation brief. Well, this shortcut lead elsewhere :-)

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon: thanks, you are entirely correct, my definition wasn't the right one, but at least it was a funny one :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(I will write my comment as an answer.)

The answer is "not necessarily" for the way IBN is defined in the problem. For a counterexample, let $R=\oplus^{\omega} \mathbb Z$
with zero multiplication.

But the definition of IBN in the problem is not the right one. It IS true that when $R$ is a commutative nonunital ring, the f.g. free $R$-modules have uniquely determined rank. The reason is that, when $R_1$ is the ring obtained from $R$ be formally adding a unit element, then the forgetful functor from the category of $R_1$-modules to the category of $R$-modules is an equivalence. The free $n$-generated $R$-module is $R_1^n$, not $R^n$.

Comment: Apologies for the delay! Thank you for editting and clearing up what goes on with both definitions and for including the functorial point of view! I have to admit that after getting used to objects having a $1$ for long time, suddenly removing the unit can be a bit confusing and difficult to track down all the properties one is accustomed to that fail in the non-unital setting.